# Compatible keyboard and mouse from china?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, hardware, wireless-keyboards

Recently installed 14.04 and it is working fine. No worries. I am just wondering if I buy the below wireless keyboard + mouse - will it work in Ubuntu 14.04? Can any one confirm please?

http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/2-4G-Wireless-Keyboard-and-Mouse-Set-Optical-Scroll-Wheel-Desktop-for-PC-Laptop-/281452431342?pt=AU_Input_Peripherals&hash=item4187df47ee

Comment: Most keyboards and mouses should work.  Is it plug and play type? Does it require installing drivers?  but if you want something 100% guarantee to work with Ubuntu , here's one from Canonical store http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=800 . Canonical is the company that supports Ubuntu.  The only disadvantage is that this item is not wireless.

Answer (score 3):

As long as it includes the little USB receiver, then it'll work.

Mice and keyboards which plug into the computer at a USB port (even if they are wireless and just have a little USB plug) follow the USB standard for human interface devices which is well supported across operating systems and devices.

*Note: sometimes mice or keyboards have "extra" buttons or features that are non-standard and so won't have any effect in Ubuntu, but the main keyboard and mouse functionality will still work, and often extra buttons can still be programmed manually.*